# How to change CollectionView size according sizes of its items

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a custom Action Sheet using CollectionView, but I have a problem with auto resizing the height. When I insert the CollectionView into the page, it takes up all the free space. What needs to be done so that the height of the CollectionView changes depending on the height of its elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<StackLayout
    Margin="60, 0">
    <CollectionView
        BackgroundColor="White"
        x:Name="CollectionViewControl">

        <CollectionView.Header>
            <Label
                x:Name="HeaderLabel"
                TextTransform="Uppercase"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </CollectionView.Header>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="0, 10" x:DataType="modalDialogs:ActionSheetItem">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="arrow_down" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        <CollectionView.Footer>
            <Button
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                TextColor="Green"
                Text="Cancel"
                HorizontalOptions="End" />
        </CollectionView.Footer>

    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

[Current UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZclV.png)

Comment: you need to calculate the appropriate height and set the HeightRequest on the CollectionView.  There is no automated way to do this that I'm aware of

Comment: I thought about this solution, but figured there are more "pretty" approaches

Answer (score 0):

> When I insert the CollectionView into the page, it takes up all the free space. What needs to be done so that the height of the CollectionView changes depending on the height of its elements?

From Jason's opinion, little rows in Collectionview, you can set a value to collectionView.HeightRequest. when item increase, the height will increase as well.

I create a property called.RowHeigth. If I add item in the CollectionView(with AddCommand), RowHeigth will increase.

```
 <StackLayout Margin="60,0">
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="CollectionViewControl"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            HeightRequest="{Binding rowHeigth}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding items}">

            <CollectionView.Header>
                <Label
                    x:Name="HeaderLabel"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    TextTransform="Uppercase" />
            </CollectionView.Header>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="0,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Image
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            HeightRequest="30"
                            IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"
                            Source="a11.png" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <CollectionView.Footer>
                <Button
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Text="Cancel"
                    TextColor="Green" />
            </CollectionView.Footer>

        </CollectionView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btnadd"
            Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
            Text="add item" />
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page5 : ContentPage
{
    public Page5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new itemviewmodel();
    }
}
public class itemviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ActionSheetItem> items { get; set; }
    private int _rowHeigth;
    public int rowHeigth
    {
        get { return _rowHeigth; }
        set
        {
            _rowHeigth = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("rowHeigth");
        }
    }
    public ICommand AddCommand { protected set; get; }
    public itemviewmodel()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<ActionSheetItem>();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            ActionSheetItem item = new ActionSheetItem();
            item.Name = "name " + i;
            item.IsSelected = true;
            items.Add(item);

        }
        rowHeigth = items.Count * 60;

        AddCommand = new Command<ActionSheetItem>(async (key) => {
            items.Add(new ActionSheetItem() {  Name = "test letter ", IsSelected=true });
            rowHeigth = items.Count * 60;
        });

    }
}
```

The ViewModelBase is class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case BindableLayaout attached to StackLayout was best solution.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).